# PowerPoint 2016 chart loses data sheet after VBA update

Tags: vba, powerpoint

After updating a Powerpoint (not an embedded excel chart) in PowerpPoint 2016 using VBA, the chart no longer allows editing of data when I right click on the chart and select Edit data.  If I select the filter symbol on the upper rHS of the chart I get this error.

> The Linked File is not Available to edit the link.  Click edit links
>   to files below.

The hyper link does nothing after clicking on it.

This is the code used to update the chart

```
For Each oSH In ActivePresentation.Slides(2).Shapes

                oSH.Chart.SeriesCollection(1).values = "Sheet1!$B$1:$B" & maxrow  ' change the series range before opening and closing the workbook object
                oSH.Chart.SeriesCollection(1).XValues = "Sheet1!$A$1:$A" & maxrow  'max number showing is 6 data points

                    With oSH.Chart.ChartData

                            'this updates the values in the datasheet
                            .Workbook.sheets(1).Range("A1:B" & lrow - 2).Value = xlWorkBook.sheets(2).Range("A3:B" & lrow).Value

                    End With
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After days of searching and experimenting, I found a solution for my problem.  I didn't create the slide or chart and discovered that the data  was in a table on the data sheet.  I edited the data in an Excel sheet and converted the table to a range.

Oddly enough, that solved my problem.